# Android - Creating database - FileOutputStream ENOENT on First Call, not Second Call

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm currently working on a Sqlite database within my app, but I'm now getting an error I wasn't getting before.

Error:
`android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)`

I noticed that it's only failing on the first attempt to create a database. I create two in my app, and the second is always OK.

If I change the order, the second still is OK. If they are the same file, or different, doesn't matter, it's always failing on the first.

It's throwing the exception when attempting to create the database to copy to.

```
private void copyDatabaseFromAssets() throws IOException {
    InputStream input =mContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
    OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(mContext.getDatabasePath(DB_NAME).getPath()); // Error on this line.

    byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
    int length;
    while ((length = input.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        output.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }

    output.flush();
    output.close();
    input.close();
}
```

The code is the same as most sample code, and it was working fine before, and still seems to work most of the time, just not the first time.

To reproduce the issue, I clear the data of the app, then re-open it, which attempts to create the databases.

Examples

```
>Start app
>Attempt to create "db.sqlite", fails.
>Attempt to create "db_2.sqlite", succeeds.

>Start app
>Attempt to create "db_2.sqlite", fails.
>Attempt to create "db.sqlite", succeeds.

>Start app
>Attempt to create "db_2.sqlite", fails.
>Attempt to create "db_2.sqlite", succeeds.
```

Any ideas on what could cause this?

Thanks.

Comment: maybe the file name?

Comment: I've actually been testing this a bunch more. I changed it to do the same filename for both databases. It always fails on the first, and the second successes. Same file name, different, doesn't matter. And it's not failing on finding the file to copy, it's failing on creating a new file, for the first time only.

Comment: maybe you need to create the file first before FileOutputStream with *new File()*? Take a look at [SQLiteAssetHelper.java](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/readystatesoftware/sqliteasset/SQLiteAssetHelper.java)

Comment: I don't think so, I tried a method that forced createdFile, but still the same issue. And that wouldn't explain why it's only failing on the first database, not the second.

Comment: Why aren't you using `SQLiteAssetHelper` to begin with?

Comment: I didn't initially write the code, was just improving it, and wasn't aware of the library. But using the library is a good idea, as now I can zip my databases and actually come out with a smaller app overall. Good idea. But I'm still wondering what would cause that other issue.